# Segment Anything Model integrated with QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing

The [Meta Segment Anything Model](https://segment-anything.com/) seems very powerful at image segmentation, and there are many development on remote sensing image segementation applications, Is there any QGIS plugins integrated Segment Anything Model like [that on ArcGIS Pro](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/pretrained-models/latest/imagery/using-segment-anything-model-sam-.htm)?

Comment: Did you try searching for this? First match for me is: https://github.com/coolzhao/Geo-SAM

Comment: Thank you for your information and good job, I will try your Geo-SAM

Comment: I noticed Geo-SAM seperate image encoding and  segmentation into two steps, it's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

With message from Spacedman, besides [github.com/coolzhao/Geo-SAM](https://github.com/coolzhao/Geo-SAM), I find following  QGIS Plugins are all in my concerning, all of them enable SAM (Segment Anything Model) to catch features, thanks for their work. I will test them to single out the right one for my work.

1. [github.com/grainseed/monitask](https://github.com/grainseed/monitask)
2. [github.com/luisCartoGeo/GeoAI_Plugin](https://github.com/luisCartoGeo/GeoAI_Plugin)
3. [github.com/BjornNyberg/Geometric-Attributes-Toolbox](https://github.com/BjornNyberg/Geometric-Attributes-Toolbox/wiki/User-Guide#segment-anything-model)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).